# Google cloud console not allowing to set innodb_log_file_size flag in mysql 5.7

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on `google cloud platform` I have created a database instance `mysql 5.7`. I am recently facing an issue that is I am trying to set the flag

```
innodb_log_file_size
```

but I don't know because of what reason gcp is not allowing me to do that now, this problem is new to me because I already set this flag once few months ago.

So when I select this flag and try to enter the size of the flag the box turn into a red one and no matter what value I set the gcp just not accept it. I am also going to share a screenshot with you for more clarity.

[image]

also a side note, all the other flag which demands some numeric value suggest the lowest and highest range of that flag as a placeholder but when I select `innodb_log_file_size` and `innodb_log_buffer_size` the value box is just blank.

So please help me out here to figure out the issue behind this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like and issue on the Google Cloud Platform Console(WEB UI), I had the same issue on my side, but you can modify any [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#gcloud) by using [gcloud commands](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#config)

I used the following command in the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell) to update the flag `innodb_log_file_size`

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --database-flags innodb_log_file_size=123567830
```

This was reported on this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160964336)